# MySql Workbench: creating relationship attributes

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

There are plenty of tutorials on how to create foreign key relationships with MySql workbench (such as https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html), but I can't find any that describe how to give a relationship attributes.

For example, here's a very simple relationship (assume the attribute "name" is the primary key for both entities). How would I create a relationship with an attribute such as this in MySql workbench?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a many-to-many relation. You need a third table for this which stands in the middle of the other tables.

```
purchases table
---------------
customer_name
product_name
date_of_purchase
quantity (optional)
```

Comment: So any relationship that has an attribute requires its own table?

Comment: If you have a 1-to-many relation then all "attributes" are stored in one of the tables.

Comment: What I mean is, if the above diagram were one-to-many, how would the "date of purchase" attribute be represented? Would the relationship still be a separate table?

Comment: The "date of purchase" would be in one of the 2 existing tables